# Delete from postgresql db according to matching regex

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone know how to remove a record from DB according to the regexp pattern? So now I have found all the required data for removal like so:

```
SELECT code, regexp_matches(code, '^(?!([EHIVPZ])).*') code
FROM "sku";
```

but cannot figure out how to remove them properly?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just put the pattern into a `delete` statement?

```
delete from sku
    where code ~ '^(?!([EHIVPZ])).*')
```

Comment: oh ~ of course, I completely forgot this. Thank you @Gordon Linoff